# How correctly iterate json in java?

Tags: java, android, json, cordova

I'm trying to write a cordova plugin.
I've the following JSON data:

```
JSONObject obj = {"amount":100, "desc":"blabla",id:123}
```

and I'm trying to iterate the JSON keys and put keys and values to `intent.putExtra(key,val)`

Example:

```
Iterator<String> iter = obj.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    key = iter.next();
    value = obj.getString(key);
    intent.putExtra(key, value);
}
```

With this code I get the error

```
error: cannot find symbol intent.putExtra(key, value);
```

Anyone can say me how correct iterate JSON data and execute `putExtra()`?

Comment: Where creating `intent` ?

Comment: Have a look to this. It will surely help you out. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30395281/is-there-a-equivalent-to-json-net-in-java

Comment: Create Intent object first

Comment: @soSlow please consider to accept one of the answer below if it helped to figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, the json you provide is not valid. It should be something like:

```
{"amount":100, "desc":"blabla","id":123}
```

Then, as said in the comments, create an intent variable outside the for loop.
And finally, you should use

```
Object value = obj.get(key)
```

because values can be Strings or Integers.

Answer (score 0):

Extension to Lino's answer.

As `Intent.putExtra(String, Object)` is not available, you need following modifications.

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{" +
                "\"amount\": 100," +
                "\"desc\": \"blabla\"," +
                "\"id\": 123," +
                "\"id2\": 123.56" +
                "}");

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Iterator<String> iter = obj.keys();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            String key = iter.next();
            Object value = obj.get(key);
            if (value instanceof Float || value instanceof Double) {
                intent.putExtra(key, (double) value);
            } else if (value instanceof Integer || value instanceof Long) {
                intent.putExtra(key, (long) value);
            } else if (value instanceof String) {
                intent.putExtra(key, (String) value);
            } /*else if (more cases go here) {

            } */
        }
```